# Trying a inline menu

Tags: html, css, menu, alignment, inline

im trying to make a simple menu, with 5 lines horizontally aligned, using CSS.

This is my base code: http://jsfiddle.net/LVCkp/

HTML

```
<div class="container clearfix">
    <!-- Conteúdo -->
    <div id="menu">
        <!-- Menu da página -->
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#main">Principal</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#corte">Cortes</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#equipa">Equipa</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#sobre">Sobre Nós</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#contacto">Contatos</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Fim class nav -->
    </div>
    <!-- Fim ID menu -->
```

CSS

```
    body{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
    width: 1024px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu{
    background-color: #000000;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#menu ul{
        margin-top: 50px;
}

#menu li {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 10px 50px 10px;
    display: inline;
}
#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 50px 15px 5px 15px;
    color: black;
}
#menu a {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Problems: I can't center the menu links and I can't get them on the middle (horizontal align) of the black bar.

Can someone help?

**EDIT:** I manage to make it better but the problem is: I cant separate the menu links, so they dont move when we have mouse over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/LVCkp/3/ I used fixed margins to achieve the position.

```
#menu ul{

    line-height: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left: 70px;
}
```

Comment: That's almost the solution, I just need to the a:hover don't move the other menu links to the sides

Comment: Well, that looks quite hard. I tried but to no avail. The padding in the a:hover is causing the text to move to the left. The most direct approach would be to remove the padding, but I am aware that the visual result would suffer a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `#menu ul` CSS to:

```
#menu ul {
    line-height: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 75px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LVCkp/1/)**

I added `text-align: center` and changed your margin-top to 75px.

Comment: Centering works but my problem now is: when you have your mouse over one link, the others move to the sides

Comment: That's because of the padding you add with `:hover`.

Answer (score 0):

try putting `float:left` on the ul and getting rid of the `fixed:position`